# Google Play Target API level requirement

Tags: android, sdk, google-play

From Google Play guides I notice that from 2 November 2020, app updates must target Android 10 (API level 29) or higher.

> When you upload an APK, it needs to meet Google Play’s target API level requirements. **New apps must target Android 10 (API level 29) or higher and app updates must target Android 9 (API level 28) or higher.**

> Every new Android version introduces changes that bring significant security and performance improvements as well as enhance the user experience of Android overall. Some of these changes only apply to apps that explicitly declare support through their targetSdkVersion manifest attribute (also known as the target API level).

It means that my new application version (updated one) could still target Api Level 28 ? Is this allowed only until November 2, 2020 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, seems so that from 2nd Nov, each update must have targetSdkVersion 29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up to November 1, 2020, you can update your application APK targeting API level 28.

From November 2, 2020, APK updates must target API level 29 i.e. Android 10

Also:

> Wear OS apps are not subject to the API level 29 requirement.
>
> Once these requirements come into effect, the Play Console will
> prevent you from submitting new APKs using older target API levels.

For more infos:https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469#targetsdk