# Make an Ionic Android app suitable with all android version

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

I'm a beginner on ionic app developpement.
I have developed my app with ionic/angular and deployed in the playstore.

The main pb is that my app is only suitable with android 11 and further.

How can i make my app suitable with all version ?

I think that the change has to be done on the config.xml.

Can you please review it and tells my what's wrong ?

https://pastebin.com/Ufp9nEPQ

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="26" />
```

Thanks in advance,
Imade

Comment: Add this in config.xml
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="31" />

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Store allows only SDK>29. (and I think 30 from a few weeks).

[Google Play Target API level requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63788879/google-play-target-api-level-requirement)